# gedit preferences grayed out

Tags: centos, gedit

I'm using `gedit 2.28.4`, on `Centos 6.4`.

When I click on `Edit > Preferences`, I can't modify anything, as everything is grayed out.

Also, I could not re-size the preferences window to locate the 'Edit' button as suggested on other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `gedit` configuration files were missing completely. Reinstalling fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the gedit preferences stored in **/usr/share/gedit** and in other root-owned places such a **gtksourceview**. you should change permission or simple try run gedit under root, to do all needed changes.

Comment: doesn't work under root either :(

Comment: Solved,
--------------------

Noticed that somehow gedit config files were missing, so simply I just re-installed it and Problem solved!!


by the way gconf, all in one configuration editor is a great tool!

Comment: please do `$su root -c 'gedit'` show there  output in terminal when you try to change options

Comment: didn't work that way @Yurij73